# Split a single row into multiple rows keeping the delimiter intact

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I am trying to split a single row in my data set into multiple rows by keeping the delimiter intact.

```
This is a sample of my input data set
|---------------------|----------------------------------------------- |
|      Group          |     Rules                                      |
|---------------------|----------------------------------------------- |
|          1          | 1. Teams must be split into two                |
|                     | 2. Teams must have ten players in each team    | 
|                     | 3. Each player must bring their own gear       |
|---------------------|----------------------------------------------- |
```

When I use Strsplit function, I get the following output:

```
df = data.frame(rules =unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$Rules),"?=[[digits]]", perl = T)))

|---------------------|----------------------------------------------- |
|      Group          |     Rules                                      |
|---------------------|----------------------------------------------- |
|          1          | 1                                              |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------- |                           
           1          | .Teams must be split into two                  |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------- |
|          1          | 2                                              |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------- |                           
           1          | .Teams must have ten players in each team      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------- |
```

My desired Output

```
|---------------------|----------------------------------------------- |
|      Group          |     Rules                                      |
|---------------------|----------------------------------------------- |
|           1         | 1.Teams must be split into two                 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------- |                           
|           1         | 2.Teams must have ten players in each team     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------- |
```

Comment: `"?=[[digits]]"` is a corrupt lookahead and POSIX character class.

Comment: It looks like you want something like `df$Group <- stringr::str_extract(df$Rules, "^\\d+")`

Comment: What's the delimiter you are using here? Are each of your `Rules` rows on a `\n` new line?

Comment: Can you post the output of `strsplit` in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to collapse each number with the following character string in column `Rules`. It throws warnings, not errors.

```
grp <- cumsum(!is.na(as.numeric(df$Rules)))
res <- lapply(split(df, grp), function(X){
  data.frame(Group = X[[1]][1],
             Rules = paste(X[[2]], collapse = ""))
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)

res
#  Group                                      Rules
#1     1             1.Teams must be split into two
#2     1 2.Teams must have ten players in each team
```

**Data.**

```
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(1, 4),
                 Rules = c(1, ".Teams must be split into two",
                           2, ".Teams must have ten players in each team"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I have more than 1000 rows with different rules, won't be able to use this method.

Comment: After `strsplit` do they *always* alternate number/string? If yes this method should work. As long as column `Rules` is of class `"character"`, not `"factor"`. Check with `str(df)`.